# Magento EE 1.11 doesn't show Auto Generated Specific Coupon Codes section?

Tags: magento-enterprise, coupon-codes, ee-1.11, not-found

On the Admin menu, select System > Configuration. Then in the panel on the left under Customers, select Promotions. But I can't see any Auto Generated Specific Coupon Codes section there as described in http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart-coupon-code-autogenerate.html

What might be the cause for this?

( Although I went through Magento documents, it is for EE 1.14 and above versions. )

Comment: which broswer you are checking? sometimes firefox does not show buttons properly. have you checked in other browsers?

Comment: Both FF and Chrome does't show

Answer (score 1):

you are checking the configuration for coupon codes.

If you want to see Auto Generated Specific Coupon Codes section then you need to follow something like this:

```
1.  On the Admin menu, select Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules.
2.  Select an existing rule, or create a new one.
3.  Set Coupon to “Specific Coupon.” Then, do the following:
a.  Select the Use Auto Generation checkbox.
b.  Complete the other rule settings as needed.
4.  Click the Save and Continue Editing button.
```

then you will see in left panel `Manage Coupon Codes` which is what I assume you are looking for.

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I can't see any Auto Generation checkbox.

Comment: when you select 'specific coupon' that time it populates.

Comment: Yes. It should be populated as in Magento EE1.14. But here i'm not getting it. Even it doesn't have in the core code

Comment: check your logs, error reports.